# Metodo Static (funcionalidades)

Tags: java

Estoy bastante verde con el tema de POO. tengo el siguiente problemilla con este metodo static: Solicita al usuario que responda "S" o "N" a una pregunta y devuelve un valor lógico TRUE/FALSE, que tengo que implemetar e invocar en la propia clase "Principal":

```
    public static boolean pedirConfirmacion( Scanner scr, String mensaje ) {
        boolean confirmacion=false;
        String respuesta="";
        System.out.println("Desea realizar otra compra?");
        respuesta=scr.nextLine();
        if(respuesta=="S") {
            confirmacion=true;
        }
        return confirmacion; 
    }
```

Comment: Prueba con `if( "S".equals(respuesta) ){`

Comment: La clave del POO está en saber qué es una instancia. Básicamente todo aquello que no sea **static** solo tiene existencia en una instancia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes un método `static` en una clase

Para llamar a ese método desde la misma clase o una clase distinta no es necesario instanciar.

```
public class Principal{
  public static boolean pedirConfirmacion( Scanner scr,String mensaje ) { 
        boolean confirmacion=false;
        Scanner scr= new Scanner(System.in);
        String respuesta="";
        System.out.println("Desea realizar otra compra?");
        respuesta=scr.nextLine();
        if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
            confirmacion=true;
        }
        return confirmacion; 
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ....
        
        if(Principal.pedirConfirmacion(scr,rpta)){
         //tu código
        }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Joshin ;-P